# Prettify fails to handle less-than in certain circumstances

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, prettify

If I try the following test case with prettify, if doesn't work correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script></head>
<body>
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">
for(int i = 0; i <things.length; i++)
</pre>
</body></html>
```

The output reads "for(int i = 0; i " which suggests it failed to handle the less-than correctly.

I have submitted a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=338&thanks=338&ts=1395008095) to the project, but I wonder if there is a workaround I can use in the meantime?

It's possible to workaround this by tweaking the input source code, e.g. changing it to "for(int i =0; i < things.length; i++)" (adding a space after the less-than). However, I can't rely on doing this, as my tool runs unattended on client sites. However, I'd be happy to hack at Prettify, or run the source code through some kind of pre-filter.

Recommendations on alternatives to prettify are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal `<` and `>` characters in HTML documents should be encoded as entities, so it should be:

```
<pre class="prettyprint lang-java">
for(int i = 0; i &lt; things.length; i++)
</pre>
```

Comment: Sorry, my minimal test case is bad. You answer solves the minimal test case but not the actual problem in my app. I will try again to extract a minimal test case.

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't work in general. As long as you replace all `<` and `>` characters with `&lt;` and `&gt;`, I think it should always work.

Comment: Because the app doesn't have the source code inline; it loads it over ajax, with content-type text/plain.

Comment: Ok, it appears after I read the data from Ajax I need to HTML escape it. This is not at all obvious, nor is it explained in the docs. However, you answer did help me figure it out, so thank-you :-)

Comment: How are you adding it to the DOM after reading it from AJAX? If you're using jQuery, use `.text()` rather than `.html()` and it will escape it for you.

Comment: I'm passing it to prettyPrintOne() which is part of prettify. The output of that (which by that point includes tags that prettify has added) I'm passed unescaped to the DOM. I'm using Angular so you have to jump through some hoops to do that. Seems natural that prettyPrintOne would do the escaping, but hey, I've got a workaround now. Prettify have rejected my request to change the behaviour.